# Can't add packages from Meteorite anymore

Tags: meteor, meteorite

mrt add package (e.g. mrg add router) is not working currently.

I've tried on several of my projects.

Anyone knows what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your meteorite version to > 0.50 using

```
npm install meteorite -g
```

You can check your current version using

```
mrt --version
```